# Why do multilevel models not incorporate a concept of 'cross-level covariance'?

Tags: covariance, random-effects-model

Multilevel models (aka hierarchical linear models, mixed models, etc.) incorporating *random slopes* can entail unstructured variance-covariance matrices decomposing level-specific heterogeneity into portions attributable to variables with random slopes and to the joint distributions of those variables with one another, and with level-specific outcomes. For example, in the two-level random slopes model of individuals $i$ nested within populations $j$

$$\hat{y}_{ij} = \beta_{0ij} + \beta_{xij}x_{ij} + \beta_{zj}z_{j},$$

where:
$$\beta_{0ij} = \beta_{0} + \varepsilon_{0ij} + \mu_{0j}\\
\beta_{xij} = \beta_{x} + \varepsilon_{xij}\\
\beta_{zj} = \beta_{z} + \mu_{zj},$$

and where:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\left[\begin{array}{c}
\varepsilon_{0ij}\\
\varepsilon_{xij}\end{array}\right] & \sim & \mathcal{N}\left(0,\Omega_{\varepsilon}\right):\Omega_{\varepsilon} = \left[\begin{array}{cc}
\sigma^{2}_{\varepsilon 0} &\\
\sigma_{\varepsilon 0x} & \sigma^{2}_{\varepsilon x} \\
\end{array}\right]\\
\\
\left[\begin{array}{c}
\mu_{0j}\\
\mu_{zj}\end{array}\right] & \sim & \mathcal{N}\left(0,\Omega_{\mu}\right):\Omega_{\mu} = \left[\begin{array}{cc}
\sigma^{2}_{\mu 0} &\\
\sigma_{\mu 0z} & \sigma^{2}_{\mu z} \\
\end{array}\right]
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

heteroscedastic variance at the individual level is decomposed into individual intercept variance $\left(\sigma^{2}_{\varepsilon 0}\right)$, variance contributed by $x_{ij}$ $\left(\sigma^{2}_{\varepsilon x}\right)$, and a covariance between individual-level $y_{ij}$ and $x_{ij}$ $\left(\sigma_{\varepsilon 0 x}\right)$. Likewise, heteroscedastic variance at the population level is decomposed into population intercept variance $\left(\sigma^{2}_{\mu 0}\right)$, variance contributed by the population-level predictor $z_{j}$ $\left(\sigma^{2}_{\mu z}\right)$, and a covariance between population-level average $\hat{y}_{j}$ and $z_{j}$ $\left(\sigma_{\mu 0 x}\right)$.<sup>†</sup>

A positive population-level covariance $\sigma_{\mu 0 x}$ means that populations with higher values of $z$ are more likely to also have higher population-level intercepts $\left(\beta_{0} + \sigma^{2}_{\mu 0}\right)$. A positive individual-level covariance $\sigma_{\varepsilon 0 x}$ means that individuals with higher values of $x$ are more likely to also have higher individual-level intercepts $\left(\beta_{0} + \sigma^{2}_{\varepsilon 0}\right)$.

**Question: Does it make sense to think about 'cross-level covariance'?**
For example, imagine a term $\sigma_{\varepsilon\mu xz}$ with an interpretation along the lines of 'A positive cross-level covariance $\sigma_{\varepsilon \mu x z}$ means that individuals with higher values of $x$ are more likely to be nested within populations that have higher values of $z$.' Is this crazy? Is it already somehow captured in the model above, and I am just not interpreting it? I'm probably crazy.

<sup>†</sup> I am aware that lots of folks approach multilevel models without the conceptual framework in place that recognizes that individual-level heteroscedastic variance can likewise be decomposed in multilevel models. Lots of statistical software that is fine modeling complex variance at higher levels does not offer a means of doing so at the lowest level (i.e. level 1), but some statistical software can estimate such models (e.g., MLwiN, JAGS, etc.).

**References**

Goldstein, H. (2003). *Multilevel statistical models*. Oxford University Press, 3rd edition.

Duncan, C., Jones, K., and Moon, G. (1998). [Context, composition and heterogeneity: Using multilevel models in health research](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0277953697001482). *Social Science & Medicine*, 46(1):97–117.

Comment: Perhaps the intra-class correlation coefficient fits into your thoughts here, where $$\rho=\frac{e_{xij}}{e_{xij}+\mu_{zj}}$$

Comment: @JaySchylerRaadt Thank you for the comment. However, no, I don't think so. *Variance partition coefficients* – of which the ICC is one kind—simply apportion variance in multilevel null models (aka intercepts-only models), though sometimes in random intercepts models. VPCs are notable for not estimating *any* covariances. See, for example, Goldstein, H., Browne, W., and Rasbash, J. (2002). [Partitioning variation in multilevel models](http://www.bris.ac.uk/media-library/sites/cmm/migrated/documents/variance-partitioning.pdf). *Understanding Statistics*, 1(4):223–232.